# PCA ? after the transformed data, are they still same with original data, (if maintain same dimensional)

Tags: pca

after the step of pca, I try to plot them (see pic)

[image: data]

example in the original (A) 2 features => pca 2 features
if I do not reduce any dimensional data, are they still have the same meaning of these data? (the picture look a bit different from them)

it is a circle example for classification data.
any seem similar example after the step of pca.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make the writing more clear. In it current form it is very difficult to understand.

Comment: thx, i just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you can see from your pics there is a change.**

From an algebra point of view, PCA is a base change. The interest of the algo is how the target base is designed: it is designed as to explain variance in the dataset. Dimension reduction is achieved trough removing some base vector with the least associated variance. **In other words : PCA is a base change to an interesting base in term of variance explained, which might be followed by a projection on a sub-base.**

**When you remove the dimension reduction component you still have a base change. Which in the general case amount to some rotation, translastion, scaling, but no significant change in the underlying data.** It seems to be what happen in your second graph : a rotation by 45° plus some scaling.